# Ext JS Store in MVC application

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have generated an application with sencha cmd (it runs through bootstrap file), it has structure like:

```
app
---\model\
----------ComboBox.js
---\store\
----------ComboBox.js
---\view\
----------My.js
----------MyController.js
----------MyModel.js
```

`My.js` is a panel where i try to use `xtype: 'combobox'` with `store: 'MyApp.store.ComboBox'`. But it throws: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmptyStore' of undefined`. My **store/ComboBox.js**:

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.store.ComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    alias: 'store.combobox',

    fields: [
        'label', 'code'
    ],
    model: 'combobox',
    data: [
        {
            "label": "RRS",
            "code": "643"
        },
        {
            "label": "USA",
            "code": "840"
        }
    ]
});
```

my **model/ComboBox.js**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.ComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.combobox',
    fields: ['label', 'code']
});
```

So It for some reason cannot properly find (`load()`?) my store class from my view. I tried to use `store.combobox`, `combobox` in store config field of the combobox - it doesnt work. I have no idea why, as I am following the "recommended" directory structure. If I put `MyApp.store.ComboBox` in global stores requires block inside `Application.js` - it just tries to load `localhost/combobox.js` (which is `NOT_FOUND` of course) and I think this is not the way at all.

**UPDATE #1**
The main question is that I have somth like this in view:

```
...
items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    store: 'MyApp.store.ComboBox',
                    valueField: 'code',
                    displayField: 'label',
                    fieldLabel: 'Type'
                },
...
```

And it doesnt instantiate store object! so the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEmptyStore' of undefined
```

Any ideas?
**UPDATE #2**
Finally:

```
...
items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    store: Ext.create('MyApp.store.ComboBox'),
                    valueField: 'code',
                    displayField: 'label',
                    fieldLabel: 'Type'
                },
...
```

Works perfectly, so why do I can not use class name (according to documentation) in store config field?

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/)?

Comment: Did you declared your store into your Controller ?